# Docker host IP mapping (forwarding)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cassandra

I'm setting up docker compose for cassandra nodes. I want the node to be visible on my host (not with the localhost but with custom local IP so using ports "9042:9042" is not an option here).

```
cassandra-node2:
image: bitnami/cassandra:latest
ports:
  - "192.168.0.1:9042:9042"
environment:
  - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=cassandra-cluster
  - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra-node1,cassandra-node2,cassandra-node3
  - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=password123
  - CASSANDRA_DATACENTER=datacenter1
networks:
  cassandra-net:
    ipv4_address: 192.168.1.103
```

According to the documentation it should be possible to do so:

```
-p 192.168.1.100:8080:80    Map TCP port 80 in the container to port 
8080 on the Docker host for connections to host IP 192.168.1.100.
```

But the problem is that I tried many IP's and ports and all are said to be not available.

```
[+] Running 0/1
- Container foodzillabackend-cassandra-node2-1  Starting                                                          
0.1s 
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 
192.168.0.1:9042 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 192.168
.0.1:9042: can't bind on the specified endpoint
`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 1
```

Where could be the problem?
I also tried using plain docker (commands) and there is the same error.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow. Please do not post links to images. Instead, paste the actual text in those images.

Comment: Best to post textual information as text, not as an image, especially if it is code or an error message. Please consider checking out the [ask], [tour] and [help] links and then [edit] your question.

Comment: Just expose the ports
ports:
      - "9042:9042"

Comment: I don't want to expose to the localhost, ports: - "9042:9042" will make it exposed to localhost